# Sublime Text3 console for JavaScript does not outputs 'return' value. How can I fix it? Thank a lot in advance

Tags: javascript, console, output, sublimetext3, return-value

```
/*example*/

function funct(){
    return "just string";
}

funct();
```

```
/* output: */
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly print the return value. `console.log(funct());` should work at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Ok, but it's very strange for Node. Isn't it?

Comment: @Chubini no, this is standard behavior for many programming languages. Functions pass data back and forth all the time, and it's not necessarily desirable (or sometimes even possible) to print it all between interactions. It's definitely a Good Idea™ to have to explicitly print data.